# Do undeleted and re-deleted questions accumulate multiple, negative, hidden flags, and is this a desired behaviour or a bug?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, privileges, hidden-features

It's not permitted to edit a self-deleted question. To do so, one must first undelete it. Having previously deleted a few of my own questions which the Math Overflow community deemed inappropriate, I later lost my question asking rights by undeleting them in order to copy the post content, before deleting them again myself.

I'm happy to accept my loss of rights may well have been justified given site policy and my relatively low competency but I wonder if this was an unintended site behaviour?

It would seem that there is an automatic algorithm in place whereby undeleting and re-deleting ones own deleted question leads to an accumulation of multiple, hidden, negative flags for the same question, which can lead to the loss of rights.

This would seem to be an unfortunate site behaviour given that one must do exactly that in order to recover one's content, including the MathJax formatting, from a self-deleted post, and is presumably an unintended feature?

Deleting of one's own post is an act of kindness to save further users the inconvenience of consuming something which may not have been received well by others.

Answer (score 8):

We generally do not reveal many details about the algorithm, but we're perfectly comfortable saying that multiple iterations of close/reopen or delete/undelete cycles does **not** have any effect on the block at all and your behavior regarding deletions is not related to your current block status on Math Overflow. We would not want to discourage users from undeleting questions and attempting to improve them, even if they only end up getting deleted again - that would be fairly counterproductive.

You may be mistaking the fact that you were able to ask your most recent question with someone having been fully unblocked. You were allowed to post a question in July because it had been at least six months since your last question, and we always allow a user to post a new question after six months regardless of their current block status. You were immediately blocked again after posting that question because the check "hasn't posted in the past six months" was no longer true and your question history still put you in block territory.

Comment: That may be the case but what led me to the conclusion was that if my recollection is right, I began drafting a new question which I literally had open at the time, so I was not in blocked territory, then I undeleted, copied and re-deleted an old question and going back to the ASK page I was in blocked territory, so the impression was certainly created that it was my own re-deletion of my question that tipped me back over the edge. But if you're certain that could not be the cause I accept that.